# Rellenar miembros de un objeto con dos funciones diferentes

Tags: c++, poo

Imaginemos que tengo un objeto a (de tipo Racional) y una función para rellenar ese racional (escribir sus miembros numerador y denominador).
Pues bien, contemplo dos opciones:

**PROGRAMA MAIN**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Racional.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Racional a, b;
  cout << "Sumar dos numeros racionales" << endl;
  cout << "RELLENA PRIMER RACIONAL: " << endl;
  //OPCION A:
  rellenarRacional(a); //Aquí envío el objeto a por referencia
  //OPCION B:
  a.rellenarRacional();  //Aquí aplico la función sobre el objeto a
}
```

**DEFINICION FUNCION PARA OPCION A:**

```
void rellenarRacional(Racional& r)
{
  cout << "Introduce el numerador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> r.numerador;
  cout << Introduce el denominador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> r.denominador;
}
```

**DEFINICION FUNCION PARA OPCION B:**

```
void Racional::rellenarRacional()
{
  cout << "Introduce el numerador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> numerador;
  cout << "Introduce el denominador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> denominador;
}
```

¿Me podríais ayudar a ver las diferencias entre ambas?
¿Cuándo debería usar una y cuando otra? Porque hasta donde leo, la mejor opción es la B en este programa.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿La función de la opción **A** es correcta? ¿No sobra eso de `Racional::`?

Comment: Perdona @eferion pero como son ejemplos hechos por mí y me ha surgido esa duda, compilar no me compila, aunque mi duda la sigo teniendo, pero tienes razón que debería de eliminar Racional:: en la opción A puesto que sería una función externa a la clase, cierto cierto. Ya lo he corregido en la pregunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Función independiente**

```
void rellenarRacional(Racional& r)
{
  cout << "Introduce el numerador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> r.numerador;
  cout << Introduce el denominador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> r.denominador;
}
```

Esta versión tiene dos inconvenientes:

- No puede acceder a elementos protegidos o privados de la clase (salvo que uses `friend`)
- No puede ser *sobreescrita* en el caso de herencias (con polimorfismo)<sup>1</sup>

La ventaja principal es que no sobrecarga la interfaz de la clase.

**Función miembro**

```
void Racional::rellenarRacional()
{
  cout << "Introduce el numerador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> numerador;
  cout << "Introduce el denominador del racional: " << endl;
  cin >> denominador;
}
```

Esta función es, básicamente, lo opuesto a la opción anterior:

- Dispone de acceso sin restricciones a todos los elementos de `Racional`
- Puede ser sobreescrita en el caso de herencias (con polimorfismo)
- Al ser una función miembro se une a la lista de funciones de la interfaz de la clase

**¿Cuando elegir una u otra?**

Pues depende de cada caso.

Como norma general podríamos decir que si la funcionalidad a cubrir es intrínseca al objeto, por ejemplo un método que pinta un objeto geométrico en una escena, la funcionalidad debería estar implementada en la propia clase. También, debido a que no soy partidario de usar `friend` salvo en casos totalmente justificados, si la función necesita acceder a métodos protegidos o privados lo suyo es que fuese una función miembro.

En cambio, si la funcionalidad es accesoria o se usan determinados patrones de diseño (por ejemplo el patrón decorador), puede ser interesante implementar funciones independientes.

Pero no hay normas escritas a fuego sobre cuando optar por un mecanismo y cuando por otro.

Notas:

- <sup>1</sup> Después de leer otras respuestas publicadas creo conveniente explicar este punto para no crear confusión. Efectivamente en C++ una función puede sobrecargarse cuantas veces se quiera:

  ```
  void func(int)
  { }

  void func(float)
  { }
  ```

  Pero estas funciones libres pueden dar problemas al trabajar con polimorfismo:

  ```
  struct POO
  { };

  struct POO2 : POO
  { };

  void func(POO *)
  { std::cout << "POO\n"; }

  void func(POO2 *)
  { std::cout << "POO2\n"; }

  int main()
  {
    POO2* poo2 = new POO2;
    POO* poo = poo2;

    func(poo);
    func(poo2);
  }
  ```

  Esta situación no se va a producir en el caso de funciones miembro siempre y cuando las mismas se marquen como virtuales:

  ```
  struct POO
  {
    virtual void func()
    { std::cout << "POO"; }
  };

  struct POO2 : POO
  {
    void func() override
    { std::cout << "POO2"; }
  };

  int main()
  {
    POO2* poo2 = new POO2;
    POO* poo = poo2;

    poo->func();
    poo2->func();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Es preferible usar funciones libres y que no sean friend (non-member, non-friend) antes que funciones miembro. (Para el caso: tu opción A)

> **Scott Meyers - Effective C++ (Capítulo 4, Ítem 23)**
>   Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions

También, hay un famoso artículo anterior, también de Scott Meyers, en http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Creo que básicamente las ideas con las que sostiene esta afirmación son los Principios de la orientación a objetos que indican que los datos deben mantenerse lo más encapsulados posible.

La forma más natural para el autor es poner estas "utilidades" en el mismo namespace que la clase, con lo que se consigue ofrecerlas como parte de la interfaz de la clase, y que pueden extenderse añadiendo otras funciones al mismo namespace, incluso en archivos separados, de la misma manera en que se hace en la STL.

Answer (score 2):

A las excelentes respuestas de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137101/2742) y [asdasdasd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137110/2742) me gustaría añadir algo más de información.

En rasgos generales se considera que el uso de funciones libres (tu Opción A) es una solución más flexible y genérica dado que puede sacar provecho de la [sobrecarga de funciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga_(inform%C3%A1tica)), la [stl](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) de C++ saca provecho de esto con [`std::begin`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) y [`std::end`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) de la cabecera [`<iterator>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator):

```
std::vector<int>     vi { /* datos */ };
std::list<float>     lf { /* datos */ };
std::map<int, int>  mii { /* datos */ };
int      formacion[100] { /* datos */ };
int formacion2d[10][10] { /* datos */ };

// equivale a vi.begin() el tipo de a es std::vector<int>::iterator
auto a = std::begin(vi);
// equivale a lf.begin() el tipo de b es std::list<float>::iterator
auto b = std::begin(lf);
// equivale a mii.begin() el tipo de c es std::map<int, int>::iterator
auto c = std::begin(mii);
// las formaciones no tienen funciones miembro! el tipo de d es int *
auto d = std::begin(formacion);
// las formaciones no tienen funciones miembro! el tipo de e es int **
auto e = std::begin(formacion2d);
```

Los [tipos fundamentales](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) no disponen de funciones miembro, por lo que no es posible obtener un iterador de una formación<sup>1</sup> llamando a la función miembro `begin`, ya que carece de ella:

```
int formacion[100] { /* datos */ };
auto a = formacion->begin(); // begin no es miembro de int!
auto b = formacion.begin();  // formacion no es un objeto!
```

Podría decirse que las funciones libres (tu Opción A) es la manera que tiene C++ de ofrecer una especie de [métodos de extensión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) como los de C#, con la diferencia que no se invocan como función miembro (tu Opción B) si no como función libre. Precisamente ese es el enfoque de el documento técnico [N4165](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4165.pdf) redactado por [Herb Sutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Sutter)<sup>2</sup> (traducción mía):

> #### Motivación
>
> **1 Código genérico**.
>
> Es bien sabido que C++ tiene desde hace tiempo el problema de dos sintaxis de llamada a función incompatibles:
>
> - `x.f()` y `x->f()` sólo se pueden usar para llamar miembros, como funciones miembro y miembros llamables; y
> - `f(x)` sólo se puede usar para llamar a no-miembros, como funciones libres y objetos no miembro llamables.
>
> Por desgracia, esto significa que el código debe conocer si la función es miembro o no. En particular, esta diferencia sintáctica derrota a la escritura de código genérico que deba seleccionar una sintaxis determinada y en consecuencia no dispone de una manera razonable ni directa de invocar la función `f` con el objeto `x` sin saber de antemano si `f` es o no es una función miembro para ese tipo. Dado que no hay una sintaxis única que pueda invocar ambas, es difícil o imposible escribir código genérico que pueda adaptarse.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> **2 las funciones no-miembro, no-amigas incrementan la encapsulación**.
>
> “Las funciones quieren ser libres”. Scott Meyers y otros han observado y enseñado que es bueno preferir funciones no-miembro no-amigas dado que éstas incrementan de manera natural la encapsulación. Sin embargo, las reglas actuales desfavorecen las funciones no-miembro porque son visiblemente diferentes a los llamantes (tienen una sintaxis de llamada diferente), y son más difíciles de encontrar. Esta propuesta eliminaría las mayores razones para seguir esta buena guía haciendo que las funciones no-miembro sean tan fáciles de usar como las funciones miembro [ ... ].

Puedes leer el resto del documento (en inglés) en el enlace que facilité antes. Ahí explica con más detalle los pros y contras de las llamadas a funciones libre (tu Opción A) y funciones miembro (tu Opción B), el documento técnico N4165 era una propuesta para C++17 que no llegó a ser introducida, proponía unificar las dos sintaxis de llamada para que fuesen mutuamente compatibles.

#### Conclusión.

Mi opinión es que ninguna opción es mejor que la otra, deberás escoger una u otra en base a las necesidades de tu proyecto.

---

1. También conocida como arreglo o en inglés: array.
2. Prominente experto en C++ miembro del comité de estándares desde hace más de 10 años y al cargo de Visual C++ en Microsoft desde 2002.