# Problema con la definición de la sobrecarga operador + como función externa

Tags: c++

ante todo y basándome en vuestras grandes explicaciones [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137098/rellenar-miembros-de-un-objeto-con-dos-funciones-diferentes/137144#137144)

Ahora estoy intentando definir una función de sobrecarga para el operador + pero externa a la clase.
Ante todo, pido que no os "asustéis" ya que la definición la he hecho yo por mí propia y puede contener lo que para ustedes son "graves" errores, pero bueno, ando aprendiendo.
La cuestión es que me falla cuando en el main realizo la suma (con sobrecarga obviamente):

```
res = p+q;
```

Veréis, esto es lo que he construido para tratar de entender la sobrecarga y a implementarla:

**MAIN:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Racional.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Racional res, p(1,1), q(2,2);

  res = p+q;
}
```

**CLASE RACIONAL:**

```
#ifndef Racional_h_
#define Racional_h_

class Racional
{
private:
  int numerador;
  int denominador;
public:
  Racional(int = 0, int = 0);
  int obtenerNumerador() const;
  int obtenerDenominador() const;
  void almacenarSuma(int num, int den);
};

#endif
```

**IMPLEMENTACIÓN CLASE RACIONAL Y FUNCIONES EXTERNAS:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Racional.h"
using namespace std;

Racional::Racional(int num, int den) : numerador(num), denominador(den) { }

Racional operator+(const Racional& r1, const Racional& r2)
{
  Racional res;
  int num,den;
  num = r1.obtenerNumerador() + r2.obtenerNumerador() ;
  den = r1.obtenerDenominador() + r2.obtenerDenominador(); //Corregido
  res.almacenarSuma(num, den);
  return res;
}

int Racional::obtenerNumerador() const
{
  return numerador;
}

int Racional::obtenerDenominador() const
{
  return denominador;
}

void Racional::almacenarSuma(int num, int den)
{
  numerador = num;
  denominador = den;
}
```

Si fuerais tan amable de ver con mi propia definición inventada porqué no funciona os lo agradecería.
Sé, que esta solución es infinitamente mejor, lo que hace es llamar al constructor pasándole directamente como parámetro la suma de los numeradores y por otra parte la suma de los denominadores, pero me gustaría saber el porqué mi versión no funciona.

```
Racional operator+(const Racional& r1, const Racional& r2)
{
  return Complejo(r1.obtenerNumerador()+r2.obtenerNumerador(), r1.obtenerDenominador()+r2.obtenerDenominador());
}
```

Sin más, **muy agradecido**, un saludo a todos.

EDITO: Estos son los fallos que recibo del compilador:

[image: Errores]

EDITO2:

```
main.cpp:9:10: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Racional' and 'Racional')
  res = p+q;
        ~^~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:743:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against
      'Racional'
operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1163:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator<type-parameter-0-0>' against
      'Racional'
operator+(typename move_iterator<_Iter>::difference_type __n, const move_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iterator:1576:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match '__wrap_iter<type-parameter-0-0>' against
      'Racional'
operator+(typename __wrap_iter<_Iter>::difference_type __n,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3698:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0,
      type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Racional'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3711:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against 'Racional'
operator+(const _CharT* __lhs , const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3723:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0,
      type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Racional'
operator+(_CharT __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Allocator>& __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3734:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0,
      type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Racional'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, const _CharT* __rhs)
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:3746:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0,
      type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Racional'
operator+(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& __lhs, _CharT __rhs)
^
```

Comment: "*Con mi propia definición no funciona*" ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Qué datos estás pasando y qué datos (incorrectos) estás recibiendo al ejecutar?

Comment: ¿Es normal que `den` resulte de sumar `obtenerNumerador()` con `obtenerDenominador()`?

Comment: Hola @Paula_plus_plus Gracias por responder, pues ya he añadido al principal los errores que me da. Un saludo. P.D: El fallo que me da arriba tienes razón, pero voy a corregirlo.

Comment: Tengo 38 años y miopía... se que puede parecer irrelevante que lo mencione, pero lo menciono por un motivo muy importante: **no veo el texto de la imagen**. ¿Podrías poner su contenido en texto en lugar de en captura de pantalla?

Comment: Mis más sentidas disculpas @Paula_plus_plus Ya lo he añadido. Mil gracias nuevamente.

Comment: ¡Mucho mejor! Gracias :)

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Qué menos! Si con lo que me ayudáis! Eso no está pagado con nada :)

Comment: Hay un "método" bastante generalizado para diseñar la interfaz de una clase, que te recomiendo, y que podría llamarse "haz como hacen los que saben". Por ejemplo, en este caso, puede ser inspirador la interfaz de std::complex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limitandonos al problema principal: el `operator+` como función externa;

Tu planteamiento es correcto; te ha faltado un único *detallito*: **informar al compilador de que dicha función existe**:

```
#ifndef Racional_h_
#define Racional_h_

class Racional {
private:
  int numerador;
  int denominador;
public:
  Racional(int = 0, int = 0);
  int obtenerNumerador() const;
  int obtenerDenominador() const;
  void almacenarSuma(int num, int den);
};

// Añade esto 
Racional operator+( const Racional &, const Racional & );

#endif
```

Si no lo haces, el compilador no sabe que tal función existe, y te mostrará un error cada vez que intentes usarla (como es tu caso).

Al declarar la función, el compilador ya sabe que es, que argumentos requiere, y que tipo de dato devuelve; de encontrarla y enlazarla, ya se encarga el *linker*.

Comment: Exactamente exacto. Fallos de novato! Gracias @Trauma :)

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te haya funcionado, pero hay algo muy importante saber. Es que los operadores que pertenecen al grupo llamado aritmetica binaria requieren dos valores uno del objeto que invocas y el otro del objeto en el lado derecha.

Mi primera pregunta es porque hiciste esto?

```
Racional operator+(const Racional& r1, const Racional& r2)
{
  Racional res;
  int num,den;
  num = r1.obtenerNumerador() + r2.obtenerNumerador() ;
  den = r1.obtenerDenominador() + r2.obtenerDenominador(); //Corregido
  res.almacenarSuma(num, den); //<--justo aquí
  return res;
}
```

Estabas intentando actualizar el objeto con el nuevo valor? recuerda que la suma no fue para el objeto al lado izquierda sino para un nuevo objeto. Si quisite actualizar el valor del objeto al lado por agregar el valor del lado derecha, necesitas usar el operador **+=**.

Espero que esto te haya servido. Es mi primera vez respondiendo en stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Hola Stephan, bienvenido al sitio. El problema no parece ser el que señalas pues es un problema lógico, y el usuario tiene un problema de compilación.

Comment: Buenas @Stephan_Edmonson Gracias por responder. Pues entiendo lo que me dices. La suma a realizar era res = p+q; entonces con el operador += lo que podría hacer (si no me equivoco) es res = res+p por ejemplo, es decir, como si actuara como un acumulador. No obstante, también creo que podría haber hecho p.operator(q) si la función es interna. Pero como dice Paula_plus_plus era fallo de compilación. Gracias por tu ayuda y por la notación.